# Center image in LaunchScreen storyboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

I have an `imageView` in my `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. I centered it with two constraints:

- Center Horizontally (Align Center Y)
- Center Vertically (Align Center X)

I also have:

- Width constraint equal to 84

What happens is that the image is just below the center. It's not perfectly centered.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is the `constant` for each constraint definitely 0?

Comment: @chedabob Yes it is, the constants are 0. The width constant is 84 though for the image.

Comment: What about height constraint?

Comment: @vienvu I do not have a height constraint. I have 3 constraints in total as shown above. The width constraint's constant is equal to 84.

Comment: "the image is just below the center" what is mean? Can you give screenshot or something?

Comment: @vienvu It was centered, I just needed to fix the mode to aspect fit, it looked as if it wasn't centered when it was scale to fill but it was in that case as well. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Give constraint as below:

```
1) Top space to superview
2) Bottom space to superview
3) Leading to superview
4) Trailing to superview

This will fill the whole nib with an imageview
```

Answer (score -1):

One easy way to do it is to add constraints on each side that are equal to the one on their opposite side to center your image. I recently did it to center a label between another label and the the remaining 3 edges of the view

[image]

Comment: You cant add constraints to image. You can add constraints only to the imageview.